# How to set the background color of a cell in GXT's AggregationRowConfig

Tags: gxt

I am trying to set the background color of an entire cell in a GXT AggregationRowConfig, and can't seem to get it done.

I am able to set the background color of the text itself using an AggregationRenderer, but the color does not fill the cell, it only colors the background of the text itself.

Normally, to color a cell in a Grid, I would do something like:

```
grid.getView().getCell(gridRowNum, gridColNum).getStyle().setBackgroundColor("yellow");
```

But the AggregationRowConfig does not seem to be just another row in the Grid, it is an independent component.

I don't know if this is tied to the issue, but nothing happens when I use the setCellStyle method of the AggregationRowConfig.

**Update:** In case it would be helpful to see the html being produced, here is what I am getting when calling setCellStyle on the AggregationRowConfig to purple and using the renderer to manually adjust the background-color of the text itself to orange.

```
<td width="60px" align="right" class="x-grid3-footer-cell background-color:purple;"><div class="x-grid3-cell-inner" style="width: 50px;"><div class="gwt-HTML"><span style="font-weight: bold; background-color: orange;">76.349</span></div></div></td>
```

Thanks in advance for any answers.

Comment: I believe `setCellStyle` requires a class not a style value as it is showing in `class="x-grid3-footer-cell background-color:purple;"` which the browser will just ignore.

Comment: Good point!  I had thought you could set any style element that way, and being no expert at HTML at all, figured the formatting on the div x-grid3-cell-inner was 'blocking' the parent tag's style from kicking in.  Works just fine when I define my own style class, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should set a `GridViewConfig` in your `GridView`. By implementing the `getRowStyle` method, you can return a CSS style for the row.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that is because you define your background inside class attribute.

```
class="x-grid3-footer-cell background-color:purple;">
```

Change to this and let's see if that helped.

```
<td width="60px" align="right" class="x-grid3-footer-cell" style="background-color:purple;">
```